# Maproute not working on prefix?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing

I have created a MVC application which works fine. Now I want to add custom keys in url and parse them, Its working only for one type of Url and not for next, so whats the issue with it.

My route entry is:

```
 routes.MapRoute(null,"client_{client_key}",
          new 
          { 
              controller = "templates", action = "contents_page" 
          });
routes.MapRoute(null,"client_{client_key}/{keyword}", 
          new 
          { 
              controller = "templates", action = "contents_pagen"
          });
```

My urls :

- `http://www.lmenaria.com/client_1`.
- `http://www.lmenaria.com/client_2`.

Above url working fine.

- `http://www.lmenaria.com/client_1/home.html`.
- `http://www.lmenaria.com/client_2/home.html`.

Both type of url not working, I am not getting `home.html` in keyword parameter in `contents_pagen` action.

My action :

```
public ActionResult contents_pagen(string client_key, string keyword, FormCollection frmColl)
{
}
```

So please let me know how can I fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Swap your route entries so that the more specific route comes first:

```
routes.MapRoute(null,"client_{client_key}/{keyword}", 
    new 
    { 
        controller = "templates", action = "contents_pagen"
    });
routes.MapRoute(null,"client_{client_key}",
    new 
    { 
        controller = "templates", action = "contents_page" 
    });
```

In the request pipeline, the action method resolver is seeing that you have a client_key route parameter, and it is matching it against the first available route.

By putting the route with the keyword param first, MVC will match that route only if your URL contains both the client_key and keyword params. Otherwise, if you only have the client_key param, it will skip the first route and match the second.